# Corrupted copy using grunt-contrib-copy

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I have an issue when copy a lot of files (images, pdf, etc) from one directory to another one. In a destination folder all these files is corrupted.
I tried to use both noProcess and processContentExclude options but it brought no results.

My copy task config looks like this:

```
copy: {
  assets_images: {
    options: {
      noProcess: ['**/*.{png,gif,jpg,ico,pdf}']
    },
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'static/images/',
    src: '**',
    dest: 'dist/assets/images/'
  },
  assets_data: {
    options: {
      noProcess: ['**/*.{png,gif,jpg,ico,pdf}']
    },
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'static/data/',
    src: '**',
    dest: 'dist/assets/data/'
  }
}
```

Could you please help me with this?

**UPDATE:**

I did some investigations and found out that binary code of the png files in the source and destionation folders are differ.

I suspect that copy task process files using wrong encoding (by default it is utf8). As I understand it process them as a binary files and utf8 is not a correct encoding in this case.

What would you recomend to do for fix this issue?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Exclude files with these extensions? Does this make any sense: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy/issues/141#issuecomment-35052411?

Comment: Since the files was corrupted after copying I added noProcess to the options to skip processing of these files. So I expect the files will be successfuly copied without modification and will not be corrupted. Is it a correct approach? And why the files is still corrupted after copying?

Answer (score 3):

### In case you have a process function

The option name is `processContentExclude`, unless you're using version `0.5.0` or above, where it changed to `noProcess` according to https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy#release-history

You can check your version with:

```
npm ls grunt-contrib-copy
```

Large copy config example from [grunt-vtex](https://github.com/vtex/grunt-vtex/blob/master/lib/config.coffee):

```
copy:
      main:
        files: [
          expand: true
          cwd: 'src/'
          src: ['**'].concat(options.copyIgnore)
          dest: "build/<%= relativePath %>/"
        ]
      deploy:
        files: [
          expand: true
          cwd: "build/<%= relativePath %>/"
          src: ['**']
          dest: "#{pkg.deploy}/#{pkg.version}"
        ]
        options:
          processContentExclude: ['**/*.{png,gif,jpg,ico,psd,ttf,otf,woff,svg}']
          process: (src, srcpath) ->
            replaceFiles = grunt.config('deployReplaceFiles') ? grunt.config('deployReplaceFiles', glob.sync(options.replaceGlob))
            for file in replaceFiles when file.indexOf(srcpath) >= 0
              log "Replacing file...", file
              for k, v of options.replaceMap
                log "Replacing key", k, "with value", v
                src = src.replace(new RegExp(k, 'g'), v)
            return src
```

### In case you don't have a process function

`noProcess` won't help if you don't have a process function.

If so, you should look at `encoding` option. https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy#encoding

Maybe try `encoding: null`, as suggested here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy/issues/64

### Either way

Try and reproduce your problem in a minimal fashion - create a Gruntfile with only one task, copying only one image. This is not a common problem and maybe some other task is the culprit here.